# How do block params work in WebAssembly (with multivalue support)?

Tags: webassembly

Blocks can consume values from the stack and push results back to it, which is cool, but I cannot find any detail on how this works.

The [spec for `loop`](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/exec/instructions.html#exec-loop) says (at 5) that the values are popped from the stack (before any code within the block gets executed), and the other block instructions (`block` and `if`) are described similarly. They all pop the params before executing the block:

loop *blocktype* *instr** end

1. Assert: due to validation, expand(*blocktype*) is defined.
2. Let [1]→[2]
   be the function type expand(*blocktype*).
3. Let  be the label whose arity is  and whose continuation is the start of the loop.
4. Assert: due to validation, there are at least  values on the top of the stack.
5. **Pop the values *val* from the stack.**
6. Enter the block *val* *instr*∗ with label .

Where are block params *popped to*? Blocks do not have their own locals, so I have no idea how to actually use the params (presumably they are not just thrown away).

The spec does not say anything about `loop` blocks popping params on each iteration, but I thought that was how they work.

I also struggled to establish whether `loop` blocks push results to the stack on each iteration, or only once, when the loop exits. Presumably, it's once, but with my ignorance on the other points, I'm not confident about that either.

I found this code in the proposal that may make things clearer (to somebody):

```
(func $fac (param i64) (result i64)
    (i64.const 1) (get_local 0)
    (loop $l (param i64 i64) (result i64)
        (pick 1) (pick 1) (i64.mul)
        (pick 1) (i64.const 1) (i64.sub)
        (pick 0) (i64.const 0) (i64.gt_u)
        (br_if $l)
        (pick 1) (return)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am new to WebAssembly, but here is how I was able to use it (replace `loop` by `block` if needed):

Following .wat adds 1 to input param

```
(module
    (func (export "myFunc") (param i32) (result i32)
        get_local 0
        (loop (param i32) (result i32)
            i32.const 1
            i32.add
        )
    )
)
```

index.html

```
<div id="out"></div>
<script>
const out = document.getElementById("out");
WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch('module.wasm'))
    .then(obj => {
        out.innerHTML = obj.instance.exports.myFunc(3);
    });
</script>
```

Alternatively, without loop param you could do the following

```
(module
    (func (export "myFunc") (param i32) (result i32)
        (loop (result i32)
            get_local 0
            i32.const 1
            i32.add
        )
    )
)
```

There are really not many examples I could find, so I am using [unit tests](https://github.com/WebAssembly/bulk-memory-operations/blob/master/test/core/block.wast#L275) as material

Comment: Thanks Yoz. I'm still confused though. So, it seems that the block cannot be entered unless the stack (only) contains the types that the block takes as params (none by default). That makes sense, and the block's params are just left on the stack. But, the spec says the values are popped from the stack, and I'm pretty sure the Multivalue proposal said loops pop values on each iteration. I'll update my question to quote the official spec.

Answer (score 1):

I too am struggling to understand the baroque way that blocks are defined in WebAssembly. This is more or less what the `loop` spec says:

- pop the m values `val_m` from the stack
- enter the block `val_m instr*` with label L

This last step means: push label L; push `val_m`; and start executing the instruction stream.

What they mean here is that the program must behave *as if* this procedure had been followed. The effect is to insert the label L (a local return address, if you like) into the stack, underneath the block parameters.

Of course no real-world implementation would do this; it is just a way of specifying the required behaviour, which people are free to implement as they see fit.

Comment: I see. It makes sense that they would define the process in abstract terms. So, if I understand correctly, the effect of `(block-instruction (param i32) ...` is to (effectively) pop an i32, push the label for the block, then push the popped i32 back to the stack, so we can have params on top of the label? So, in practice (IIUC), this means that the stack no longer needs to be empty when we enter the block??

Comment: Does that mean that `loop` instructions do not really pop anything on each iteration, except in the same abstract terms as when the block is entered initially (just under the hood stack operations that ensure the label is in the right place)? I'm still pretty vague on how this all works, but your answer was helpful. I don't have enough rep to upvote anything yet, but will come back and fix it when I have.

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding of the process. (What I'm currently struggling with is how validation proceeds when a frame has become unreachable. The test cases in Yoz's link have many examples of this, and it seems that you have to be strict about things.)